# Sequelize timezone postgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize-js, timezone

Estou realizando um insert com sequelize, porem quando retorno a informação que foi gravada, retorna com 3 horas acima da que está no postgres. 
json Insomnia:

[image: json Insomnia]

Dado no postgres:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei alterar o timezone no sequelize, porem isso impacta novamente no banco.

o horário correto é o do postgres, logo após executar o metódo do create e retornar o objeto deveria retornar o mesmo valor salvo no postgres.

Poderiam me ajudar por favor?

Comment: No JSON, o "Z" no final [indica que a data está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)). E 20:24 em UTC é o mesmo que 17:24 no offset -03:00 (o `-03` indica que está 3 horas atrás de UTC, então 17:24-03 é igual a 20:24Z. Ou seja, a data/hora (o instante, o ponto na linha do tempo) é exatamente o mesmo. O que muda foi somente a representação do mesmo (ambos são formas de se indicar o mesmo instante). Agora se vc quer mostrar essa data e hora em algum timezone específico, aí é outra história...

Comment: Agora entendi! Muito obrigado!! Conseguiria me informar algum meio de retornar a mesma data e hora no json caso for possível?

Comment: Depende de onde/como vc consulta a data e mostra ela (vai ser em JavaScript mesmo? Ou em outra linguagem? etc). Por favor clique em [edit] e adicione esses detalhes. Lembrando que, se for "apenas" questão de converter e/ou formatar a data, já tem várias perguntas no site sobre isso, então não esqueça de fazer uma boa busca antes, para se certificar que seu problema já não foi resolvido antes :-)

Comment: Sim javascript, estou usando o model do sequelize com as funções de timestamp, apenas gostaria de conseguir converter o retorno do json para o fuso horário correto, pois caso eu precise imprimir essa data ela venha de acordo com a qual foi salva no banco de dados.

Comment: Mas aí que tá, no banco foi salvo "alguma data", não necessariamente a data que vc vê. O postgres está mostrando ela no fuso horário brasileiro, mas nada garante que o que está gravado lá está nesse fuso horário. Inclusive, se não me engano, vc pode mudar as configs de fuso do banco e ele mostra a data nesse outro fuso. O que está gravado é algum valor que equivale a 20:24Z **e** também 17:24-03. Ambos são o mesmo instante. De qualquer forma, conversão entre fusos com o `Date` do JS é bem limitado, pesquise sobre libs como Moment.js e date-fns